# How to use a date format in ms excel which matches US and Germany?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel report which contains sales details for certain months. The colum header has dates like the one below..

3/1/2009    4/1/2009    5/1/2009    6/1/2009    7/1/2009    8/1/2009    9/1/2009    10/1/2009
3375    2475    3600    5400    2925    0   2250    3150
3375    2475    3600    5400    2925    0   2250    3150

The dates are in mm/dd/yyyy format. Now when my German user opens the report, the dates are getting messed up.
 It get changed to the one below;

12/1/2005   12/1/2006  12/1/2007  12/1/2008
 3375      2475      3600          5400

This is because they have dd/mm/yyy format.
Can somebody help me with a macro where i can prepare a report matching both my US and German users?

Comment: I recommend a thorough look at http://xkcd.com/1179/. No, seriously, do you have a way of changing the process that creates the report so that it contains a sane date format?

Comment: Are those dates stored as text? If not - Excel stores them internally as numeric values - and only applies the regional format, so it should not be an issue. Try converting them to dates instead of text.

Comment: thanks peter...the dates are stored as Date format.. they are not in text format.. still i was reported this issue...

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use something like:

```
 If MsgBox("German format?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then

    Selection.NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy;@"
    Else
    Selection.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy;@"

  End If
```